# store an image displayed in the view controller into an array by clicking the image

Tags: objective-c

I have a view controller. And I have several images displayed in it. If I click on a particular image, that image has to be stored in an array. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using collection view or tableview you can get the image containing cell by selecting the cell. Then you can get the image from that cell. Or if you're using only Imageviews then you can set gesture or button and get the image. But this is not a good method. I recommend to use collection view

Answer (score 0):

Just add a gesture recognizer to the image, or even easier - make it a button.
Every time an image is clicked, catch the event, extract the image object from the sender and store it into the array.
Hope this is what you need.

Comment: I made them buttons. But How am I able to store the imagefile?

Comment: Retrive the image from the sender. Once get a pointer to the UIImage you can store it.